# Validating username/pswd from .txt file in python - unwanted looping

Tags: python, passwords

```
passwordAttemptLoop = 0
    print("You have chosen to login!\n")
    while passwordAttemptLoop == 0:
        usernameAttempt = input("Please print your username below\n")
        passwordAttempt = input("Please print your password below\n")
        for line in open("usrnmPswd.txt","r").readlines():
            loginDetails = line.split()
            if usernameAttempt == loginDetails[0] and passwordAttempt == 
loginDetails[1]:
                passwordAttemptLoop = passwordAttemptLoop + 1
                startQuiz()
            else:
                print("Your username and/ or password is incorrect! Please 
try again!")
```

The code shown above is made as the login system of a quiz program I am trying to create. It is made to read lines (columns) of the usrnmPswd.txt file (where the usernames/passwords are stored). If the username/ password are correct, it should start the quiz by calling the function startQuiz(). If username and/ or password are incorrect, it will tell the user that it is incorrect and ask them to input their username/ password again (due to while loop). I am getting 2 problems with this code:

1)The output looks like this if the username/ password are correct:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XRNn.jpg

I think this is checking each individual line and printing the incorrect usrnm/pswd message until it reaches the line where both username and password are correct.

2)Similarly if username and/or password are incorrect, the output I get looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcz5b.jpg

I understand that the problem is the looping of the validation of username/password but as i am a beginner programmer, i do not know what code to use in order to fix it.

Any help/ code would be much appreciated if you know how to make the incorrect username/password message be printed only once. Thanks

Comment: post your output here rather than using an image

Comment: The link shows an image of my output? What’s wrong with it?

Comment: It's difficult to debug and it's not a recommended practice at SO. Refer to [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Ok sorry. Shall I post full code of my program?

Comment: no problem. please post your code, file and your output.

Comment: Please click this link: https://repl.it/repls/DearLeafyBluebird

Comment: Or you can click this link: https://ws.onehub.com/folders/h55exiyk and download all of my files which includes external .txt files and the main python file if its more convenient for you than the link I sent you

Comment: added the code in the answer. Please comment if you have any questions @Archit123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a few changes if you want the code to work the way you intended. Few things that you did wrong were

1. Your output shows the error messages until you find the right set of credentials because you are checking the username and password of every line of the file

   `usernameAttempt == loginDetails[0] and passwordAttempt == loginDetails[1]`

   every time the above condition fails, it will automatically goes to the else block and executes those statements
2. The following statement is useless in your program

   `passwordAttemptLoop = passwordAttemptLoop + 1`

   You are giving the user as many attempts as there are in your text file  which is a bad practice. So, limit the maximum number of attempts that user can try before exiting the program. Whenever user enters a wrong set of credentials, decrease the value of `passwordAttemptLoop`
3. Once the user logged successfully, it will call the `startQuiz()` function. But once control is returned back to `login()` function again after the execution of `startQuiz()`, it will continue to execute the remainder of the program which is not what you intended
4. Also, according to `usrnmPswd.txt` file, you can ignore the first two lines of the file as they are the headers of the file

I modified the code to correct the above errors

```
def login():

    passwordAttemptLoop = 3 #attempts you want to give the user
    print("You have chosen to login!\n")

    while passwordAttemptLoop > 0:
        usernameAttempt = input("Please print your username below\n")
        passwordAttempt = input("Please print your password below\n")

        for line in open("usrnmPswd.txt","r").readlines()[2:]:
            loginDetails = line.split()
            if usernameAttempt == loginDetails[0] and passwordAttempt == loginDetails[1]:
                startQuiz()
                return

        print("Your username and/ or password is incorrect! Please try again!")
        passwordAttemptLoop = passwordAttemptLoop - 1

    print('You are out of login attempts. Please try again later')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly! Program runs nice and smoothly now and a maximum of 3 login attempts really is a good idea. Thanks again!

Comment: yw, please let me know if you have any question regarding this :) @Archit123

Answer (score 0):

You guessed it right. It is reading line by line till it finds the line which matches the username. `readlines` reads line by line. Instead use `searchfile`

Try this:

```
#Login Function      
def login():
        passwordAttemptLoop = 0
        print("You have chosen to login!\n")
        while passwordAttemptLoop == 0:
            usernameAttempt = input("Please print your username below\n")
            passwordAttempt = input("Please print your password below\n")

            searchfile = open("usrnmPswd.txt", "r")
            for line in searchfile:
                if usernameAttempt in line: 
                    loginDetails = line.split()
                    if usernameAttempt == loginDetails[0] and passwordAttempt == loginDetails[1]:
                        passwordAttemptLoop = passwordAttemptLoop + 1
                        startQuiz()
                        searchfile.close()
                    else:
                        print("Your username and/ or password is incorrect! Please try again!")


#MAIN/START MENU Function
```

- `searchfile` reads the file and looks for the line containing the 'username' passed by the user and returns it. You can then do operations on that line.
- You should keep a number of maximum attempts allowed, with a message to contact the administrator or similar appropriate message in case maximum allowed attempts is crossed. Otherwise the person trying to login will be stuck at this step forever, if he/she has actually forgotten the password

Comment: In your code when `startQuiz()` returns the control to calling function, it'll resume reading the rest of the file which is not needed

Comment: @yklsga Thanks for pointing it out. Moving `searchfile.close()` inside the for loop will take care of that

Comment: Not quite right. If you close the file, it only results in an `ValueError`. You need to exit the function/program once the control is returned from `startQuiz()`